# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: allocLargeObjectOrArray: [B, size 4K

Tags: java, weblogic

Application is down due to Out of memory error. On checking the Weblogic logs, i got the below exception. what should be done to avoid this?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: getNewTla

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: allocLargeObjectOrArray: [B, size 4K.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: allocLargeObjectOrArray: [B, size 4K.

at weblogic.utils.io.Chunk.<init>(Chunk.java:293)
at weblogic.utils.io.Chunk.getChunk(Chunk.java:141)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.<init>(ChunkOutput.java:112)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.create(ChunkOutput.java:156)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.<init>(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.<init>(ServletResponseImpl.java:155)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.MuxableSocketHTTP.<init>(MuxableSocketHTTP.java:111)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ProtocolHandlerHTTP.createSocket(ProtocolHandlerHTTP.java:65)
at weblogic.socket.MuxableSocketDiscriminator.dispatch(MuxableSocketDiscriminator.java:131)
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:901)
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:840)
at weblogic.socket.EPollSocketMuxer.dataReceived(EPollSocketMuxer.java:215)
at weblogic.socket.EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:177)
at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application has a memory leak.

You have to find it and perform the needed changes.

I usually use JProfiler to find memory leaks, but there are a lot of tools that can help you.

Take a look at this video: [Find a memory leak using JProfiler](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/04/in-screencast-below-i-show-strategy-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running web logic on JRockit you can use following commands to get some information on heap:

1. Find pid of web logic node running web app.
2. Go to jrockit lib directory.
3. Command to get summary of heap: 
   jrcmd {pid} heap_diagnostics
4. Command to generate heapdump (hprof): 
   jrcmd {pid} hprofdump filename={filename}.hprof

As mentioned in above comments you could start inspecting heap dump using MAT (IBM memory analyzer) to find out memory leaks. Best way is to inspect histogram with filter on your application package/classes. Look for unusually high number of instances of your application classes.

Answer (score 0):

As @jfcorugedo mentioned it might be due to memory leak or simply you are running with far less memory than what your application needs (just trying increase the heap and do a run). First look at your GC log. Also you can use tools like MAT if you have taken memory dump